# iterating new pandas dataframe to a new excel sheet in the same workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to create a web scraper that that get information of a similar table (with different values) from multiple pages (though in my case it's scrapping html stored in text documents)

The following code is a snippet from my program where a data frame is made from a previously made list along with the header. It then opens a new excel workbook and writes the data frame to the workbook in a worksheet with a specified name (which changes with each iteration)

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # imports BeautifulSoup
import pandas # imports pandas
from pandas import ExcelWriter

#creates the lists
list_of_rows = []
list_of_lists = []
list_of_headers = []

for File in range(len(os.listdir())):
    if os.listdir()[File].endswith('.txt'):
        file = open(os.listdir()[File])
        data = file.read()
        file.close()

        #Converts the text file into something the program can use
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
        tables = soup.find_all(class_="overthrow table_container") #Creates a resutset that will show all of the tables with this class name

        #grabs from the header
        find_header = tables[2].thead
        header = find_header.find_all("th")

        #grabs from the table
        find_table = tables[2].tbody #creates a tag element from the desired table and highlights the tbody section
        rows = find_table.find_all("tr") #creates another resultset signle out the elements with a tr ta

        #for loop that creates the list for the header
        header_list = []
        for i in range(len(header)):
            if i < 14:
                pass
            else:
                list_of_headers.insert(i,header[i].get_text())

        #for loop that creates the lists for data frame table
        for j in range(len(rows)):
            row_finder = rows[j]
            tag_row = row_finder.find_all("td")
            for i in range(len(tag_row)):
                list_of_rows.insert(i,tag_row[i].get_text())
            list_of_lists.append(list_of_rows)
            list_of_rows = []

        #creates the DataFrame
        df = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_lists,columns=list_of_headers)

        writer = ExcelWriter('testing document.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=os.listdir()[File])
        writer.save()
        df.drop(df.index)
        print("worked once")

    else:
        pass
```

and I get the following error code.

```
worked once
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 47, in <module>
    df = pandas.DataFrame(list_of_lists,columns=list_of_headers)
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 314, in __init__
    arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5617, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5696, in _list_to_arrays
    coerce_float=coerce_float)
  File "C:\Python3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5755, in _convert_object_array
    'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
AssertionError: 56 columns passed, passed data had 28 columns
```

So between the first line printing the code "this worked once" and the fact that it does, in fact, create the excel file, my guess is the problem is it's not creating a new worksheet? THough this code could not be doing at all what I think it is.

Comment: The error is in the code _after_ the print statement. Too bad we can't help, since you haven't shown us the code.

Comment: Is this code thats running in a loop? If so, please show the loop also.

Comment: edited with te full code

Comment: Please show example .html inputs.

Comment: how exactly would I do that?

Comment: also, if it helps, I know for a fact that the initial list, the initial dataframe and the initial worksheet are made properly.